# How to get rid of the ZeroDivisionError: float division by zero

Tags: python, numpy

I keep running into the error float division by zero and can't understand why I am getting it. However when I run the code originally given to me (written and run in matlab) no errors occur.

The Code

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from astropy import constants as const


#Part 1: Exploring Rotation Curves


M = 10**42 #Approximate mass of the Milky Way (kg)
G = const.G #Universal gravitational constant (m^3 kg^-1 s^-2)
r = np.linspace(0, 3e20) #Radii (m)
rkpc = r*(3.24e-20) #Radii (kpc)
plt.figure(1)
plt.title('Rotation Curves for Three Mass Distributions') 
v1 = np.sqrt(G * M / r) # Orbital velocity in system with central mass (m/s)
M_prop = np.linspace(0, M) # Array of masses increasing proportionally with radius
v2 = np.sqrt(G * M_prop / r) 
M_dens = (M * (r / (max(r)))**3) 
v3 = np.sqrt((G * M_dens) / r)
plt.plot(rkpc, v1/1000, 'b', label = 'Constant M_{r}')
plt.plot(rkpc, v2/1000, 'k', label = 'M_{r} \propto r')
plt.plot(rkpc, v3/1000, 'r', label = 'M_{r} \propto r^{3}')
```

I know the error is occurring due to the two following lines

```
M_dens = (M * (r / (max(r)))**3) 
v3 = np.sqrt((G * M_dens) / r)
```

I assume it is happening due to the max(r) but would someone be able to shed more light on why this is happening? Potentially a fix?

Comment: Because you divide by zero...

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: Since you start `r` with a 0, do not change it, and then divide by it, I'm confused about where you are unclear on what's happening.  You fix it by not insisting on a division by zero.

Comment: I understand that. I should've been more clear, why does it like that input in matlab but not python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry if this doesn't work, I'm a bit rough with math commands like these.

In this line:

```
r = np.linspace(0, 3e20)
```

r will start as 0. Later in this line:

```
v3 = np.sqrt((G * M_dens) / r)
```

you divide by r, which is 0.
Anything divided by 0 is undefined, so Python doesn't like it and raises the error.

Comment: I understand that. I should've been more clear, why does it like that input in matlab but not python?

Comment: Not too familiar with Matlab, but you might want to run some tests to make sure it's not just ignoring the exception

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how matlab handles divide by zero but it's possible to change the numpy behaviour using `np.errstate`.

```
a = np.arange(-5, 5.)
b = np.arange(-2, 8.)
with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
     res0 = a / b
     res1 = b / a 
print(res0, '\n', res1)
# [ 2.5    4.   -inf -2.   -0.5   0.  0.25   0.4  0.5  0.57142857] 
# [ 0.4   0.25 -0.   -0.5  -2.   inf  4.    2.5   2.    1.75]
```

Alternatively create a function which can set the inf, -inf results to a useful default value.

```
def do_div( a,b, def_val=np.inf):
    with np.errstate(divide='ignore'):
        res = a / b                   
        res[ ~np.isfinite(res) ] = def_val
    return res

print( do_div( a, b, 100 ))
# [  2.5   4.   100.  -2.    -0.5   0.     0.25   0.4  0.5  0.57142857]
print( do_div( b, a, 100 ))
# [  0.4  0.25  -0.  -0.5  -2. 100.  4.  2.5  2.  1.75]
```

Setting the errstate for divide to 'ignore' suppresses the warning.  Numpy returns plus or minus infinity for a divide by zero.  The do_div function sets any infinity values to a default.  In my work that's most often zero.  I've used 100 here so it's easy to see.  Matlab probably does something similar returning infinity or an alternative default value and not issuing an error or a warning.